# Web page stuck while the web worker faced an endless loop

Tags: javascript, worker

I am working on a web project that needs quite a few calculations, and I use a web worker to do so. There is also a button on the web page that should terminate the worker's calculation whenever the user clicked it. However, when I wrote an endless loop inside the web worker to test, the webpage stuck and I cannot interact with it.

```js
//When the worker is created
worker = new Worker("./scripts/testWorker.js");

//When the button is clicked
worker.terminate();
worker = undefined;
```

How to solve this problem? Or are there any other ways to reach the goal of performing breakable calculations?

Comment: See if the [this linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46371746/2055998) is relevant to you.

Comment: I solved this problem. The problem is that my infinite loop contains a postMessage function. And it post too much messages to the main thread that the main thread stuck.

Comment: Glad to hear. You may want to post your own answer and accept it afterwards, if you feel that it can help others in a similar situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the endless loop of the worker thread, there is a `postMessage` function. Hence, the `onmessage` function in the main thread is called rapidly. Therefore, the main thread stuck when the worker starts. Deleting this `postMessage` inside the endless loop of the worker thread solved this problem.